# Is it possible to recalculate the `srcset` image used if browser window is resized?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, srcset

Is it possible to get `srcset` to recalculate the browser window size once the page has loaded, and thus update the image its using.

The reason you'd want to do this is because if on a desktop you have your browser window compressed, load a site, then make the browser window bigger, it will just scale the "small.jpg" (as set in the `srcset`) so the user will end up with a pixilated image.

I started make a jsfiddle to show the issue, but it dosnt work well, as i think `srcset` is calculated by the browser window, rather than the jsfiddle results grid.

If you are interested you can copy and paste below this into a blank `html` file and run it in a localserver (must be on a local http:// server  so you can view the network debugging tab to see which image the browser has loaded). Running it in the browser via the file url using `file:///` wont allow you to see which image is loaded via the network debugging tab.

```
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">

            <img 
                 src="http://i.imgur.com/DoWeH0X.jpg?1"
                 srcset="http://i.imgur.com/QV9vace.jpg?1 1400w, http://i.imgur.com/ZqkR6Bk.jpg?1 800w, http://i.imgur.com/gltBZ06.jpg?1 300w" 
                 alt="#"
            >

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question deserves more upvotes. Thanks!
What did you choose to work best for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
var img = document.getElementById('resizeMe');

window.onresize = function() {
    img.outerHTML = img.outerHTML;
}
```

Which will cause the HTML to be sent through the parser again, causing the browser to reload the image according to the srcset.

Of course you should probably include some logic to detect if the screen size has changed to a size outside of the current range so the image isn't reloaded every single time the user resizes the window slightly.

---

Or, you could clone the node, insert it before the current node, then remove the old node.

```
var img = document.getElementById('resizeMe');

window.onresize = function() {
    var clone = img.cloneNode(true);
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, img);
    img.remove();
}
```

Which will also cause the parse to re-render the html, but will consume more resources.

Comment: Your upvoted answer gets me: ```NoModificationAllowedError: DOM Exception 7: An attempt was made to modify an object where modifications are not allowed.``` The second answer fixes the problem, I'd recommend removing the first example as it no longer seems to work.

Comment: Neither of these work when I tested in Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m

Comment: @Patrick How are you testing that? (can you include a link to an example of it not working?

Comment: @Mark the first version works for me, but I have to do `img = document.getElementById('resizeMe');` in the _onresize_ handler. I guess this is because else, the second time the handler is called, `img` is a stale reference, which we cannot replace (reassign its `outerHTML`).

Answer (score 2):

i found this to force a re-render

var img = document.getElementById('my-element');

img.srcset = img.srcset;

Comment: Could probably be shortened to:  
`document.getElementById('my-element').src+='';`